# Unable to resolve path to module in NextJs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint

[image: i got this error]
i got error 'unable to resolve path to module' i am using NextJs 13

```
`{
  "extends": [
    "next",
    "airbnb-base",`your text`
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "linebreak-style":[0,"error","windows"],
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "import/extensions": ["error", "ignorePackages", {
      "js": "never",
      "jsx": "never",
      "ts": "never",
      "tsx": "never",
      "":"never"
    }]
  },
  "settings": { 
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Here is my  Eslint config, i tried all solutions that i have found but it did not help

Answer (score 1):

you need to create, in your project root directory, `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` (only if you use typescript in your project) and define aliases. Example of my `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      //path to your components folder, starting from root
      "@/components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@/lib/*": [
        "src/lib/*"
      ],
      "@/helpers/*": [
        "helpers/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next"]
}
```

Once you have created this file, restart your project.

*P.S. if you still facing issues with aliases, check very carefully your path, and path to your folders, letter by letter.*

Comment: i wrote like this 
"@/components/*": [
          "./src/components/*"
        ]
but i still have this problem

Comment: Give me a path to your components. Your components are placed in `root/components` or in `root/src/components`?

Comment: hi, my components placed in root/src/components, also i got rid of error by changing @/ to ../  is it good or bad solution?